# How to randomly select a value in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

Please note that I have read similar questions on this site but none worked for me and this seem unique at least for now/to me.

I have the following array;

```
[{"advert_id":"advert1"},{"advert_id":"advert2"},{"advert_id":"advert3"},{"advert_id":"advert4"},{"advert_id":"advert5"},{"advert_id":"advert6"},{"advert_id":"advert7"}]
```

I actually got the data when I fetch information from database with Laravel `$adverts = Advert::select('advert_id')->get();`

How can I randomly select an element from it?

I tried using `array_rand($adverts)` but had errors (array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given )

Comment: `json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: That is not a PHP array, you're using JSON notation. The error you give suggests that you converted it to an object at some point. You probably used `json_decode` for that. As Darren pointed out, you should set the second argument to `true`.

Comment: Alternatively, you may try `$adverts = get_object_vars($adverts)`, to convert the object to an array.

Comment: Ok, lemme try that out

Comment: Wow, alot of vote down but I don't mind cause `json_decode($json, true);` worked for me. Thanks to @Darren for the answer and @Jorn for the explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proper answer so that you can hopefully mark it correct, allowing others to find it as well.

You're referencing an `array` but parsing an object.
Now using `json_decode()` as below and parsing the second parameter, you explicitly ask for an array in return instead of an object.

```
json_decode($array, true);
```